# /sbin/service omniNames status

Tags: redhawksdr

`/sbin/service omniNames status`  returns `omniNames (pid  2529) is running...`. 
 Is this OK?

The processes I see after I start an `Waveform` are:

```
Aug16 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.pid

Aug16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager

14:06 pts/1    00:00:00 DomainManager DEBUG_LEVEL 3 DMD_FILE /domain/DomainManager.dmd.xml DOMAIN_NAME REDHAWK_DEV FORCE_REBIND false PERSISTENCE false SDRROOT /home/me/redhawk/sdr

14:06 pts/1    00:00:00 DeviceManager DCD_FILE /nodes/DevMgr_host.mycom.com/DeviceManager.dcd.xml DEBUG_LEVEL 3 DOMAIN_NAME REDHAWK_DEV SDRCACHE /home/me/redhawk/sdr/dev SDRROOT /home/me/redhawk/sdr
```

Am I missing any processes even though the Waveform seems to run fine?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. You could further verify what domains/nodes/waveforms/etc are running via the `nameclt list [domain]` command.

An example would be:

```
nameclt list REDHAWK_DEV
```

This will list something like:

REDHAWK_DEV

- waveform1
- waveform2
- node1
- ...

If you wanted to see which component(s) are inside of your waveform running in the REDHAWK_DEV domain execute the following command:

```
nameclt list REDHAWK_DEV/waveform1
```

This will result in

waveform1/

- component1
- component2
- ...